# Version of dependency not found

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services

I have an Android App that is published in Google Play.

I tried to publish a new version and the Google Play console asked me to update the sdkVersion to 30, it was 29.

I modifyied to 30, and Android Studio warned me that I should update to 32 the sdkVersion. So I changed: **compileSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** to 32.

Then Android Studio warned me about new version of dependencies, so I updated all to the latest version sugested.

Now, trying to run the emulator of Pixel 3a API 30 I get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.a1ci.progresivasCCVB, PID: 4088
    com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: LocationServices.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null, message=null}
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.getResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:3)
        at com.example.progresivas.MainActivity.obtenerÚltimaUbicación$lambda-1(MainActivity.kt:73)
        at com.example.progresivas.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$3EOEADo-cNmUgUpdjLu9Ud7BkM4(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.progresivas.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onComplete(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: LocationServices.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null, message=null}
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ApiExceptionMapper.getException(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zag.zad(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zaE(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zaD(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zai(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:58)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Why I get warned about not finding the version 17 when I configured the API version as 20.0.0?
This is only because I have to change something the emulator configuration?
Since the app was working fine in the emulator before this changes, and the installer I created works fine on my Android 12 smartphone, it is safe to create a bundle and publish in Google Play?